# Read And Write Data to SharePoint Site Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I am new to Sharepoint and currently I want to write a function where I can read and write data to Sharepoint pages. This is the structure of the URL I want to connect to read and write data: https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/SubSite/SubSite1/SitePages/Home.aspx 
Then, I open the connection to it by using:

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/SubSite/SubSite1/");
clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("user@mycompany.com", password);
```

I use `SecureString` for the password 
Then, I load site pages in to a list and read each field to examine:

```
List colList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Site Pages");
FieldCollection colfield = colList.Fields;
IEnumerable<Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List> resultCollection = clientContext.LoadQuery(
        clientContext.Web.Lists.Include(
        list => list.Title,
        list => list.Id));
clientContext.Load(colList);
clientContext.Load(colfield);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Then I loop through every field to examine

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++){  
    ListItem lst = colList.GetItemById(i);
    foreach (Field field in colfield){
        clientContext.Load(field);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        var val = lst[field.Title];
    }
}
```

I figured out that there are some fields in colList, such as: DataSource, etc. containing this exception:

```
The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested
```

My question is how can I properly connect to Sharepoint site pages to read and write data in them?

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating through all the fields of `colList` but including only `Id` & `Title` fields in

```
 clientContext.Web.Lists.Include(
        list => list.Title,
        list => list.Id));
```

That's why you are getting above exception.

You have to `Include` all the fields you want to retrieve OR just load the list `clientContext.Load(colList);` and don't Include anything if you want to retrieve all the fields.